# A Windows Web server not sending emails,

Tags: php, windows, email, smtp, wamp

I am trying to create a windows based web server. The following are installed on it -

1) Apache 2.2.22

2) PHP 5.3.5

3) MySQL 5.5

However, I am into some trouble. The trouble is that the server is not sending email, generated by the applications running on the web server.

It would be really grateful if someone can help me with this issue.

```
<?php 
    phpini_set("sendmail_from", "info@example.com"); 
    $to = 'abc@example.com'; 
    $subject = 'the subject'; 
    $message = 'hello'; 
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
?>
```

Comment: It would really greatful if you could post the code that is being used to generate the emails.

Comment: the code that is used to send mail is -
`
<?php
phpini_set("sendmail_from", "info@example.com");
$to      = 'abc@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>`

Comment: Yes mate. That would be the one :)

Comment: the mail addresses are changed in actual implementation.

but the mail is still not received.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you did not install an SMTP server (he is the one responsible of sending emails)

Comment: Usually setting up mail server is not enough. You need to configure ports and php.ini (sendmail_path) also.

Comment: But how to configure an SMTP server on windows.

Is it possible to relay email using SMTP server which is inbuilt into Windows?

Or Do I need a external SMTP address?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the mail server section in php.ini?

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.vatican.va
smtp_port = 25
```